# Duplicate call ReceiveMessage method with AWS-SQS SDK Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, task, amazon-sqs

I try to implement a custom SqsListener with AWS-SDK Java but he don't care about withWaitTimeSeconds.

When I start this code:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100)
@Transactional
public void testSQS() {

    try {

        String fifoQueueUrl = "example_stack.fifo";

        ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(fifoQueueUrl)
                .withWaitTimeSeconds(10)
                .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);


        logger.info("START=" + LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        List<Message> sqsMessages = amazonSQS.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
        logger.info("END=" + LocalDateTime.now().toString());

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(sqsMessages)) {
            logger.info("empty");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error.", e);
    }
}
```

- My queue is empty (I never send a message in the queue)

First call take 10 seconds because I configured with WaitTimeSeconds at 10 sec.
So my problem is why after my first call at receiveMessage() it don't wait 10 secondes every time?

See log you will see he wait 10 seconds then retry and return empty list of message without waited.

See log:

```
2019-02-08 10:05:42 - START=2019-02-08T15:05:42.859
2019-02-08 10:06:03 - END=2019-02-08T15:06:03.119
2019-02-08 10:06:03 - empty

Seconde Time:

2019-02-08 10:06:03 - START=2019-02-08T15:06:03.223    
2019-02-08 10:06:23 - END=2019-02-08T15:06:23.181
2019-02-08 10:06:23 - empty
2019-02-08 10:06:23 - START=2019-02-08T15:06:23.284
2019-02-08 10:06:23 - END=2019-02-08T15:06:23.422
2019-02-08 10:06:23 - empty


3th time

2019-02-08 10:06:23 - START=2019-02-08T15:06:23.525
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - END=2019-02-08T15:06:43.255
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - empty
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - START=2019-02-08T15:06:43.358
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - END=2019-02-08T15:06:43.454
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - empty
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - START=2019-02-08T15:06:43.557
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - END=2019-02-08T15:06:43.557
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - empty
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - START=2019-02-08T15:06:43.659
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - END=2019-02-08T15:06:43.709
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - empty
2019-02-08 10:06:43 - START=2019-02-08T15:06:43.813
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:03.354
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - empty
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - START=2019-02-08T15:07:03.455
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:03.546
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - empty
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - START=2019-02-08T15:07:03.649
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:03.650
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - empty
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - START=2019-02-08T15:07:03.755
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:03.756
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - empty
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - START=2019-02-08T15:07:03.859
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:03.860
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - empty
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - START=2019-02-08T15:07:03.963
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:03.963
2019-02-08 10:07:03 - empty
2019-02-08 10:07:04 - START=2019-02-08T15:07:04.067
2019-02-08 10:07:04 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:04.067
2019-02-08 10:07:04 - empty
2019-02-08 10:07:04 - START=2019-02-08T15:07:04.169
2019-02-08 10:07:04 - END=2019-02-08T15:07:04.169
```

Version -> AWS-SDK 1.11.125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It's a conflict with AmazonSQSAsyncClient with spring-cloud-aws-messaging dependency.

If I create my own AmazonSQS client bean that work fine.